# Get last action of a user on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to retrieve last actions (likes, reactions, comments) made by an user (me) on Facebook.

So the question is simple: is it possible to do this using graph.facebook.com?

I've searched in StackOverflow and tried with Graph API Explorer on Facebook but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, you can´t access the Activity Log with the API.